# How to display ion search bar in ion select box in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

hi friends tried all the possible ways to get the serach bar in ionselect not able to get the ion search bar in the select box    tried to get from html as well as tsfile let me know is it possible to get the ionserach in ion select

```
 ## another way tried in  ts file code ##
        this.countryAlertOpts= {
           inputs: [
            {
              name: 'title',
              placeholder: 'Title'
            },
          ],
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              handler: data => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Save',
              handler: data => {
                console.log('Saved clicked');
              }
            }
          ]
        };



 ## htmlcode ##



 <ion-item> <ion-label>Select Country</ion-label>
                    <ion-searchbar name="countrysearch" [ngModel]="countrysearch" (ngModelChange)="searchCountries($event)" placeholder="Serach for Countries"></ion-searchbar>
                    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="country" interface="popover" name="country"  (ngModelChange)="getStates($event)">
                    <ion-option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="{{c.id}}" [selected]= "c.id == this.country">{{c.name}}</ion-option>
                    </ion-select> </ion-item>
```

Comment: Your use case is not clear.Can you provide more details?

Comment: Hello Sampath thanks for the reply check this link for my requirement https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionic-popup-select